# Selected value in dropdown is always the first value - Jquery

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to make a birthday select form(1 select form for month, day, and year) where the number of days changes depending on the month chosen.  i'm successful in populating the select field with options, but the problem is when i'm trying to select(clicK) an option, the result will always be "1". Is it because the dropdown menu is still part of the select tag? if so, how will target only the default select box and not the dropdown list? Or if you have any other way to solve this. thanks, jquery newbie here.

```
$("#day").click(function(){
   var m = $("#month").val();
   if ( m == 'Apr' || m == 'June' || m == 'Sep' || m == 'Nov'){
       $("#day option").remove();
       for (var x=1;x<=30;x++){
            $('<option>'+x+'</option>').appendTo($("#day"));    
       };          
   };
});
```

Comment: `Is it because the dropdown menu is still part of the select tag? ` of course! By clicking you are erasing all options, leaving the first one selected. And the selection of the days is also a click.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the 'change' event of the month box like this:

```
$("#month").change(function(){
   var options = '';
   var m = $(this).val();
   if ( m == 'Apr' || m == 'June' || m == 'Sep' || m == 'Nov'){
       $("#day option").remove();
       for (var x=1;x<=30;x++){
            options += $('<option>'+x+'</option>');    
       };          
   };
   options.appendTo($("#day"))
});
```